# Перекодировка .csv файла в php

Tags: php, кодировка

Доброго времени суток. Пишу обработчик .csv файла. Проблема следующая: не понимаю, как перекодировать загружаемый .csv файл с помощью скрипта Перекодировать в UTF-8. Скрипт выводит содержимое файла, но не читает кириллицу.. Довольно мало опыта в программировании, прошу помочь понять, как перекодировать. Спасибо.

```
<?php

    $uploaddir = "uploads/"; 
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES["somename"]['name']);
    (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["somename"]['tmp_name'], $uploadfile));
           //Добавление и расположение файла в нужную директорию 

    $row = 1;
    if (($handle = fopen("$uploadfile", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $num = count($data);
            $row++;
            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            }
        }
       fclose($handle);
    }  // обработчик .csv файла 

?>
```

p.s

пробовал перекодировать так, но никакой реакции. Объясните, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так):

```
$dir = $uploadfile;
echo mb_detect_encoding($uploadfile);
$dir = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($uploadfile), "UTF-8", $dir);
```

Comment: Перекодировать во что? Что в вашем коде не работает. Больше подробностей, больше.

Comment: Прошу прощения, за то, что сразу не уточнил. Перекодировать в UTF-8. Скрипт выводит содержимое файла, но не читает кириллицу. Это не работает.

Comment: А в какой кодировке у вас файл .csv приходит?

Comment: mb_detect_encoding показывает что файл приходит в ASCII кодировке.

Comment: Может файл стоит загрузить в переменную (для второго случая) `$dir = file_get_contents($uploadfile);`